# Is there a sequence of $C^2$ functions approximating $\max(0,x)$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functions, sequence-of-function

I know that the sequence
\begin{equation*}
f_n(x):=\begin{cases}\sqrt{x^2+\frac{1}{n^2}}-\frac{1}{n},& x\ge0, \\\\ 0,&\text{otherwise},\end{cases}
\end{equation*}
is a $C^1$ sequence pointwise convergent to $\max(0,x)$, with the further property $|f'_n(x)|\le M$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and for some $M\ge0$.

However, this sequence of functions turns out to be not twice differentiable and therefore not $C^2$. I tried to find a new sequence, but I was unsuccessful. So my question is: can someone provide a sequence of functions $(f_n)_n$ such that

- $(f_n)(x)\to\max(0,x)$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$;
- $f_n\in C^2(\mathbb{R})$;
- $f_n(0)=f_n'(0)=f_n''(0)=0$;
- $|f_n'(x)|\le M_1$, $|f_n''(x)|\le M_2$ for all $n$ and $x$ and for some $M_1,M_2\ge0$?

Comment: "$\lvert f_n(x)\rvert\leq M$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and for some $M\geq 0$" is not true --- look at $\lvert f_n(M)\rvert$.

Comment: Anyway, you cannot have a uniform bound on the second derivative $\lvert f''_n(x)\rvert<M_2$ for all $n,x$.  That would have implied the sequence of first derivatives $(f'_n)$ is uniformly equicontinuous and we get a contradiction using [this question](/question/4045355).

Comment: @user10354138 you are right, I meant $f'_n$, that was a typo. I edited. The link doesn't work, though.

Comment: Oops, accidentally deleted the s in `questions`.  [This link](/questions/4045355).

Comment: Ok, this is interesting. In the known example, I don't have the equicontinuity of $(f'_n)_n$ and that's why the limit is not necessarily differentiable. So, now a new question arises: since the sequence I presented is the one often used to prove that if $f\in W^{1,p}(\Omega)$, then also the positive and negative parts $f^+,f^-\in W^{1,p}(\Omega)$. What about the positive and negative parts of functions in $W^{2,p}(\Omega)$?

Comment: The functions $f_n(x) = \boldsymbol{1}_{x>0} x e^{-\frac{1}{nx}}$ should satisfy all your conditions, except the last one as was pointed out. In fact, $f_n$ is $C^\infty$ and satisfies $f_n^{(k)}(0)=0$ for all $k\in\mathbb{N}$. As for your second question, try $f(x)=x$ over $(-1,1)$, you'll see that it is $W^{2,p}$, but its negative and positive parts aren't.